# What breaks down in the theory of affine hyperplane arrangments?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, co.combinatorics, discrete-geometry, algebraic-combinatorics, hyperplane-arrangements

It appears to me that there is a substantial amount of combinatorial algebra and geometry supporting the theory of central hyperplane arrangements (See Topics in Hyperplane Arrangements,  Aguiar and Mahajan).

What breaks when extending this theory to the affine case? Is there a simple relationship between the affine and central case which makes all of the results of Tits algebras/incidence algebras/Dynkin idempotents apply?

I ask this as a machine learning theorist very interested in leveraging many of the algebraic and combinatoric results of this beautiful field, but in my domain we care strictly about the affine case. Since it appears many of the texts and papers in this area concern central arrangements, I'd like to know if those results somehow apply trivially to the affine case, before I embark on developing a deep understanding of the field.

Comment: I'll also note that there is some relationship between the Tits semigroup of an affine arrangement and subsemigroup of the cone of the arrangment, but is this enough to use a large majority of the results in the field? eg. JKS isomorphism etc.

Comment: My knowledge of the implications of the foregoing semigroup relationship is quite limited to make a judgement on this.

Comment: There is a fairly trivial way given an affine hyperplane arrangement to construct a central hyperplane arrangement from it: namely, take the *cone* over that arrangement. And this coning process is not silly, when it comes to the algebra: for example, the (extended) Shi and Catalan hyperplane arrangements are affine, have remarkable combinatorics associated to them, and the cones over these arrangements are free- this is a result of Yoshinaga, building on work of Terao, and answering a conjecture of Edelman and Reiner, see https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00222-004-0359-2

Comment: The other thing to say here is that the theory of "multi-arrangements" is a way to blend affine and central together: multi-arrangements are central arrangements but where each hyperplane has a multiplicity associated to it, which you can think of as "how many parallel translates of this hyperplane are in my affine arrangement." The basic algebraic geometric set up for central arrangements works for multi-arrangements in exactly the same way: we can talk of free multi-arrangements, and so on. I think that coning and taking the associated multi-arrangement of an affine arrangement are related

Comment: My notes at http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~cis610/sp06stanley.pdf deal with affine arrangements.

Comment: @SamHopkins Thanks for the insights. Are there any references on multi-arrangements?

Comment: I like these notes of Yoshinaga: https://arxiv.org/abs/1212.3523. I realize now however that the module of logarithmic derivations/freeness might not be the “algebraic” aspect of central hyperplane arrangements you were most interested in.